# Crystal Reports - Calculate Number of Weeks between dates including year

Tags: crystal-reports

I run a report that includes a calculation for the number of weeks between two dates.

```
IF(DatePart ("ww",Date({Documents/Document/HeaderData.ShipDate}),crMonday))-(DatePart ("ww",Date({Documents/Document/HeaderData.TenderDate}),crMonday))<> 0 THEN (DatePart ("ww",Date({Documents/Document/HeaderData.ShipDate}),crMonday))-(DatePart ("ww",Date({Documents/Document/HeaderData.TenderDate}),crMonday))
```

This is fine for dates in the same year, but we are finding that dates in 2013 do not calculate correctly. Is there a way to include a year calculation into the week that will give us a true value?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `DateDiff` instead of subtraction:

```
DateDiff (Intervaltype, Date1, Date2, firstDay)
```

i.e.

```
DateDiff (("ww", Date({Documents/Document/HeaderData.ShipDate}),
     Date({Documents/Document/HeaderData.TenderDate}), crMonday)
```

(**Note:** the above code should be on a single line, but it is broken up over two lines for readability).

Comment: Thats seems to have done the trick! Great work, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Anonymous downvoter -- seriously, we're doing this again?  You're going to downvote the same question again?